# Is there any benefit to completing the pipe levels in Mario Run?

Tags: super-mario-run

I recently unlocked the black pipe level by getting all of the black coins in the game, and it's really hard! Will I earn anything for completing it? It seems like you don't get any reward for completing the first two pipe levels.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I beat it and you get nothing.

Answer (score 0):

I beat them. They're just for fun (although there is a little message at the very end).